# android_core tutorials: no communication to roscore

Tags: ros, communication, android-core, ros-master-uri, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I successfully installed and builder android_core. I encountered some problems but could fix them. I installed the android_tutorial_camera and android_tutorial_pubsub on the android device. Allthough both apps can run, there is no connection to the computer where the roscore runs. rosnode/rostopic list doesn't show any marks of the android device.

I tried it with 2 computers and 2 android devices with all possible combinations:

- Laptop Ubuntu 10.04 with ROS electric
- Desktop Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS fuerte
- Samsung galaxy ace with android 2.3.3
- Samsung galaxy tab 2 with android 4.0.4

None of the following URI's worked:

- http: //< my_IP >:11311
- http: //localhost:11311
- http: //noe-laptop:11311

For the pubsub tutorial I also adapted the network adapter (link in comment).

Please help me!
Thank you, Noë

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59539/android_core-tutorials:-no-communication-to-roscore/) by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) on 2013-03-29**:
Links:
android_core: http://ros.org/wiki/android_core
network adapter pubsub: http://answers.ros.org/question/45314/wrong-network-adapter-with-inetaddressfactorynewnonloopback/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just wanted to make sure that (1) your `Android` device can communicate `roscore` machines (eg. by `ping`, `http` etc)? (2) Is `my_IP` your `roscore` machine not your `Android` right? (3) No space b/w "http" and "//" ok?

---

Update) For (1), if 2 computers can communicate over `IP`, there's no way that a node on a computer connects to `roscore` that's running on another machine.

In general, it's worthwhile to check [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup), although some of the checkups there might not work for `Android`.

I'm not 100% sure if `ping`ing in `LAN` succeeds in any situation, but at least `http` should go through. Easiest (not the most optimal though) way to check connection b/w 2 machines if `roscore` runs on Ubuntu might be running http server on it and access from `Android`. Can be done as:

```
On_Ubuntu$ sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then on Android, open `http://IP_Ubuntu`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) on 2013-03-29**:
(1): no I do not manage to make them communicate (2) my_IP is from my laptop on which I run the roscore (3) I put the space there because I'm not allowed to post links already since I'm a new user of this website. Thanks already !

**Comment by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) on 2013-03-30**:
Update for (1):  The master is my Linux machine and the android app generates its own roscore.
I made a web server with apache2 but, although both computer and tablet are connected to the same wifi AND with a USB cable, I cannot connect to the web server from my tablet.

**Comment by [noe_vb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4546/noe_vb/) on 2013-03-30**:
Do I have to setup a separate network or so?
Thank you!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-30**:
Ok your issue is most likely in network, not in `ROS`. Make sure Android can establish IP connection to your Ubuntu. Btw running `roscore`on both ends shouldn't be a problem.